# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt not working inside a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I am trying to build a new docker image by adding some python packages to my base docker image. The `sudo docker build -t myimage1:cuda10.2 .` runs without any issues but I cannot import any of the packages in the new image. I am using `sudo docker run --gpus all -it myimage1:cuda10.2` to run the image. Can somebody help me understand what am I missing here?

Dockerfile

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04

WORKDIR /rapids/notebooks/

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt

```
ujson
```

This is the trace for docker build

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/5 : FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04
 ---> 98901cabda0a
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /rapids/notebooks/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 162a9bb732c7
Step 3/5 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> 7bb48a384987
Step 4/5 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip &&     pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 5f3ca4ed3f93
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.2
Successfully installed pip-20.2.4
Collecting ujson
  Downloading ujson-4.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (181 kB)
Installing collected packages: ujson
Successfully installed ujson-4.0.1
Removing intermediate container 5f3ca4ed3f93
 ---> 58e94a2c4c98
Step 5/5 : COPY . .
 ---> d5897f4da4ff
Successfully built d5897f4da4ff
Successfully tagged myimage1:cuda10.2
```

If I run the image and do `pip install ujson` This is what I get

```
Collecting ujson
  Downloading ujson-4.0.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (179 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 179 kB 947 kB/s
Installing collected packages: ujson
Successfully installed ujson-4.0.1
```

The only difference is that the ujson package is cp37 while that installed by Dockerfile is cp38? Can somebody explain why the packages installed are for different Python versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rapids containers there's a virtual environment named `rapids` where all of the packages are installed and is activated in the default entrypoint for the container. You should change your `RUN` command to:

```
RUN source activate rapids && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```